# Integrating redirection payment method for Rapyd Payment

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, integration, payment

I want to integrate Rapyd payment for my eCommerce website.
Customer will be redirected to Rapyd site to complete payment and after completing payment customer will be redirected to site.

https://docs.rapyd.net/build-with-rapyd/docs/hosted-checkout-page-integration-steps
I am following this with example and trying same example given in this link for my website but every time I am getting error for "UNAUTHENTICATED_API_CALL".

So can you please suggest a full example for this and how to call this API ? Or what is wrong with my API call ?

Here is my API call with a postman with an error message. I checked there is no whitespace in my request.

[Authorization parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL0y5.png)
[Request body and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5izjo.png)

please suggest a full example for this and how to call this API

Comment: Rapyd payment provider not supporting to integrate payment method in .net website. Their support service is too much bad/week